# Changing the dimensions of a poster

Tags: paper-size, posters, a0poster

I want to change the dimensions of the following A1 poster to be 22 x 28 inch. I do not want only to "stretch" it to manually fit the new dimensions but to have a new arrangement of the text according to the new dimensions size. I tried many different options but none of them:

1. Change the dimensions into non-proportional new dimensions (A1 is 23.4 X 33.1 and 22/23.4 not equal to 28/33.1)- so geometry doesn't fit.
2. Work well with xclolr, itemize and the other packages in the code.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a1,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\columnsep=100pt 
\columnseprule=3pt 
\usepackage{pdfposter}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 

\usepackage{times} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{figures/}} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption} 
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\begin{document}

    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.75\linewidth}
        \Huge \color{NavyBlue} \textbf{Title} \color{Black}\\ 
        \huge\textit{Title}\\[2cm] 
        \huge \textbf{Name}\\[0.5cm]
        \huge University\\[0.4cm] 
        \Large \texttt{email} \\
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=20cm]{logo.png}\\
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace{1cm} 

    \begin{multicols}{3} 

        \color{Navy} 

        \section*{Research Question}

        \begin{itemize}

            \item blah blah

        \end{itemize}

        \color{SaddleBrown} 

        \section*{In This Paper}

        \begin{itemize}

            \item bla bla
        \end{itemize}


    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To explain my dificulty, if I add the following lines in the begining of the code:

\documentclass[portrait,a1]{a0poster}

\setlength{\paperwidth}{22in}

\setlength{\paperheight}{28in}

It is just stretch the paper, so part of the text disappear

Comment: Are you aware of the **geometry** package? If not, take a look.

Comment: Use the option **showframe=true** to help to understand the effects of the different parameters.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, consider accepting the best answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not enough to change the paperwidth, you also need to reset the textwidth. With geometry it works fine:

```
\documentclass[a1,portrait]{a0poster}

\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=100pt
\columnseprule=3pt
%\usepackage{pdfposter}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=22in,paperheight=28in,margin=2cm}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.75\linewidth}
        \Huge \color{NavyBlue} \textbf{Title} \color{Black}\\
        \huge\textit{Title}\\[2cm]
        \huge \textbf{Name}\\[0.5cm]
        \huge University\\[0.4cm]
        \Large \texttt{email} \\
    \end{minipage}

    \begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=20cm]{example-image}\\
    \end{minipage}

    \vspace{1cm}

    \begin{multicols}{3}

        \color{Navy}

        \section*{Research Question}

        \begin{itemize}

            \item blah blah

        \end{itemize}

        \color{SaddleBrown}

        \section*{In This Paper}

        \begin{itemize}

            \item bla bla
        \end{itemize}


    \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Be aware that a0poster inserts postscript specials which aren't really suitable for pdflatex. Imho a saner solution would be to use article.cls, set the page size with geometry and copy the few needed lines for the font sizes from a0poster.cls and a0size.sty.

Comment: Thanks! a bit too late (I already printed the A1 size poster) but it works...

Answer (score 4):

With the default `scrartcl` (article) class

```
\documentclass[usegeometry,fontsize=30pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=22in,paperheight=28in,margin=2cm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=100pt
\columnseprule=3pt
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{wrapfig,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.75\linewidth}
    \Huge \color{NavyBlue} \textbf{Title} \color{Black}\\
    \huge\textit{Title}\\[2cm]
     \textbf{Name}\\[0.5cm]
     University\\[0.4cm]
    \Large \texttt{email} \\
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[b]{0.25\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=20cm]{example-image}\\
\end{minipage}

\vspace{1cm}    
\begin{multicols}{3}        
        \color{Navy}        
        \section*{Research Question}        
        \begin{itemize}         
            \item blah blah         
        \end{itemize}       
        \color{SaddleBrown}     
        \section*{In This Paper}        
        \begin{itemize}         
            \item bla bla
        \end{itemize}       
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```